# New User: User 2 user chat

Tags: support, chat

I have only been with you guys for a couple of days and I mostly on the http://stackoverflow.com forum under the tag c# or XML

I have answered a few questions and got into discussions in Comments that went out of hand.
Then the system proposes a user to user chat as not to pollute the system.

Is there any way to initiate a user 2 user chat without getting this warning?

Contact a higher level person directly?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a forum. there is a chat feature but if youre new you need to be invited by a user with more rep

Comment: Regarding a particular question, causing the promote to link early (in which case; I'm all for that) or private messaging particular users **before** they've interacted with your question

Comment: If you are looking for clarifications or help with figuring out if your c# answer was appropriate, you can always ask in the [c# chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c). In general though, if someone takes issue with an answer that is usually an opportunity for improvement.

Comment: OK I am really sorry I even asked this. I am in no way looking for ways to circumvent the system and annoy other people. I thought there was an obvious way I was missing somewhere. If I want to speak to a higher rep person it is because I want to conform with the system and ask him about what to do. Not to yell at them for editing my posts.

Comment: If someone has edited your post and you want more details just @them, that's the usual thing to do. If it gets too long promote to chat. Everything you have done has been correct

Comment: @Richard Tingle It was but an example, I felt like contacting a few people directly, but it seems as something that is not done around here. I have only been around for 5 days, what do I know? I thought this was the forum to ask... right? (I love it here and would like to be a productive asset to my community)

Comment: @user2888973 Yes, we like to keep it "about the questions and answers here rather than about people". You were absolutely right to ask about it here. P.s. don't worry about the 2 downvotes, on meta downvotes often mean "We disagree with your idea (of personal messages)" rather than "This question is bad". It has been discussed trying to change that, but hey ho

Comment: @Richard Tingle Honestly... they can vote me down to kingdom come. I got the answer I wanted, Gained more insight in how to be part of this community, and learned about it's rules. That alone is worth a -5 to me (And I get a +2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to the Chat Profile of the person. E.g https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2509901/precious-tijesunimi and Click **Start a new room with this user** to start a private chat with the user.

If you don't know the chat profile of the person, Just go to the stackoverflow profile of the person and replace `stackoverflow.com` with `chat.stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 11):

You can manually create a new chatroom on [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) and invite the other user to join you there.

Note that chat requires 20 reputation before anyone can participate, so this won't work with brand new users. (For that matter, that automatic "let's take this to chat" feature doesn't work for users with insufficient reputation, which is sometimes inconvenient.)